# Mono Embed: Mutex for synchronize managed and native

Tags: mono, embed, native, mutex

There is a native c++ application (linux) that load mono assembly.
How to to share mutex (or his analogue) between managed and native parts of same application?

something like this:

## native part:

```
native_lock_mutex(&db_mutex);
// do something with db
native_unlock_mutex(&db_mutex);
```

## mono part:

```
managed_lock_mutex(db_mutex);
// do something with db
managed_unlock_mutex(db_mutex);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must expose the native mutex to managed code, something like this:

C code:

```c
pthread_mutex_t* managed_get_mutex ()
{
    return &db_mutex;
}

void managed_lock_mutex (pthread_mutex_t *mutex)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock (mutex):
}

void managed_unlock_mutex (pthread_mutex_t *mutex)
{
    phtread_mutex_unlock (mutex);
}
```

C# code:

```cs
class NativMutex {
    [DllImport ("nativeLibrary")]
    public static export IntPtr get_managed_mutex ();

    [DllImport ("nativeLibrary")]
    public static export void managed_lock_mutex (IntPtr mutex);

    [DllImport ("nativeLibrary")]
    public static export void managed_unlock_mutex (IntPtr mutex);
}
```